# SQL aggregate with the previous result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

| Year1 | Year2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | 2014 | 1 |
| 2014 | 2014 | 2 |
| 2014 | 2015 | 3 |
| 2014 | 2016 | 4 |
| 2015 | 2015 | 5 |
| 2015 | 2016 | 6 |
| 2015 | 2017 | 7 |
| 2015 | 2017 | 8 |

and I need to write a SQL query to give me this:

| Year1 | Year2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | 2014 | 3 |
| 2014 | 2015 | 6 |
| 2014 | 2016 | 10 |
| 2015 | 2015 | 5 |
| 2015 | 2016 | 11 |
| 2015 | 2017 | 26 |

The group by can help with grouping year1 and year2 but my problem is the cumulative result from the past aggregation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregate in your groups first, and then use a windowed aggregate:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Year1,
           Year2,
           SUM([Value]) AS [Value]
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY Year1,
             Year2)
SELECT Year1,
       Year2,
       SUM([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY Year1 ORDER BY Year2) AS [Value]
FROM CTE;
```